# IIS hangs, ultimately crashes when debugging ASP.net 3.5 web application in Visual Studio 2013, Windows 8.1

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2013

As mentioned in the title:
- ASP.net web application (built targeting 3.5)
- Visual Studio 2013, running as Administrator
- Windows 8.1

No issues when debugging web applications built targeting 4.0 or 4.5. Hang occurs in both w3wp.exe or iisexpress.exe, so not limited to either process.

Anyone else experiencing this problem? I have an old Windows 7/VS 2012 VM lying around that I can use in the short term, but ultimately it's easier to rely on a single machine.

Comment: Are there any EventLog entries that could give a hint about what's going on? You could also enable Fusion logging http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net in order to see whats going on.